# How to dispatch state in class component using React-redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to get my head around Redux.

Here's the **MainMap.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { 
    TouchableWithoutFeedback,
    StyleSheet,
    Keyboard,
    PermissionsAndroid,
    Platform, 
    View,
    Button,
    FlatList,
    Dimensions,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Text
} from 'react-native';


import * as placeAction from '../../store/actions/place/place';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';


class MainMap extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state={
            //....
            destinationName: [],
            destinationAddress: [],
            //...
        };

        //......

        this.addPlaceHandle = this.addPlaceHandle.bind(this)
    };
    //....


    // Dispatch a place
    addPlaceHandle(name, address){
        this.props.addingPlace(name, address);
    }

    render(){
        const {container, map, listOfSearchBars, buttonView, button, next} = styles
        const { destinationCoords, userLatitude, userLongitude, initial_UserLatitude, initial_UserLongitude } = this.state;
        //....
            return(
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.hideKeyboard} >
                    <View style={container} >

                        <View style={buttonView}>
                            <TouchableOpacity style={button} onPress={() => {
                                this.addPlaceHandle(this.state.destinationName, this.state.destinationAddress);

                            }}>
                                <Text style={next}>Next</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            )
        }

        componentWillUnmount(){
            Geolocation.clearWatch(this.watch_location_id);
        }

    }

//}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex: 1
    },
    map:{
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject
    },
    listOfSearchBars:{
        ...
    },
    buttonView:{
        ...
    },
    button:{
        ...
    },
    next: {
        ...
    }
});


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    addingPlace: (_name, _address) => dispatch(placeAction.addPlace(_name, _address))
})

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MainMap)
```

Basically, the `MainMap.js` is like Google Map. You search a location, choose it from the suggestions, and it'll show the direction for you.

After loads of *async/await* functions and `this.setState()`, the name and the address from the location we choose will be added to the `this.state.destinationName` and `this.state.destinationAddress`, respectively.

I've successfully done that. Now I want to dispatch that data which is the name & address to the store

**place.js** in **actions**:

```
export const ADD_PLACE = 'ADD_PLACE';

export const addPlace = (name, address) => {
    return {
        type: ADD_PLACE,
        placeData: {
            name: name,
            address: address
        }
    };
};
```

Here's the **place.js** in **reducers**:

```
import { ADD_PLACE } from '../../actions/place/place';
import Place from '../../../src/models/place';

const initialState = {
    places: []
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case ADD_PLACE:
            const newPlace = new Place(
                action.placeData.name, 
                action.placeData.address
            );
            return {
                places: state.places.concat(newPlace)
            };
        default: return state;
    }
}
```

But I get this error when I click the button:

[image: Error]

Any answers and recommended resources are deeply appreciated !

Comment: I think your error is not related to redux itself, in your *place.js* , `Place` is undefined, which your are importing from `src/models/place` file. check there, why `Place` is undefined.

Comment: OMG!. I export the Place incorrectly @@. Thanks so much for the help hussain. Such a typo =)))

Comment: <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I did `import` the `Place` incorrectly
It has to be:

```
import {Place} from ''
```

Thanks @hussain for helping me